# Как мне тут создать цикл с проверкой, если аргумент парный то он должен делиться на 2

Tags: c++, функции

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>
using namespace std;

void func(int num, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, num);
    while (num--)
    {
        cout << va_arg(ap, int) << endl;
    }
    va_end(ap);
}

int main()
{
    func(5, 1, 2, 3,4,5);

}
```

Comment: Парный - значит четный? Тогда просто проверьте, что остаток от деления на 2 равен 0

Comment: да, четный, Тогда просто проверьте, что остаток от деления на 2 равен 0 - как это сделать ?

Comment: Остаток от деления N на M - `N%M`...

Comment: а откуда мне взять N и M ?

Comment: @Mike, будет проще если вы укажете что конкетно подается на вход и что вы хотите получить, во избежание терминологической путаницы.

Comment: Если честно у меня было такое задание: Напишите функцию, которая находит произведение только четных чисел из тех, что к ней передаются в качестве параметров. Вызвать функцию не менее трех раз с количеством параметров 5, 10, 15. Я его начал делать так но потом запутался

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>
using namespace std;

void func(int num, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, num);
    int total=1; // тут будет произведение
    cout << "произведение чисел";
    while (num--)
    {
        int x = va_arg(ap, int);
        if(x%2==0){ // если остаток от деления на 2=0 (число четное).
            total*=x;
            cout <<" "<<x;
        }
    }
    va_end(ap);
    cout <<" = "<< total<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    func(5, 1, 2, 3,4,5);
    func(10, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

}
```

Comment: спасибо большое )

Comment: `x%2==0` UB....